# Could a normative population ever be non-heterosexual?

Tags: evolution

In the modern documentary called "Bi the way", one American geneticist said that if modern American youngsters may as well be functionally bisexual, then some generations ahead Americans could be possibly born with a strong inclination towards the bisexual lifestyle. If we let aside the futuristic theory according which bisexuality should become an evolutionary norm concerning the human species in the long run, then is there a strong bio-sociological possibility that modern societies could transform normally to sexually fluid homogeneous spaces?

So the problem is if humans will naturally evolve to a species which is homogeneous in terms of dynamic bisexual differentiation, while in the meantime producing stable behavioral norms.

Then it has to be decided if society will integrate this procedure naturally or through competition.

Comment: I doubt it's a biological question in this formulation. And I personally have no idea, what "normative population", "functionally bisexual", "evolutionary norm by necessity", "bio-sociological possibility" or "sexually fluid homogeneous spaces" mean.

Comment: @mad-scientist - I accept that Valintine Wiggin's wording was a bit incoherent, particularly the infusion of terms which I'm pretty sure were coined on the fly. However, I think the academic scenario and theoretical implications were quite clear.  Hence why I took the time to reply!

Comment: Evolution does not think. It does not have a goal or aim in that sense. It just is, because some individuals within a population manage to reproduce. What it comes to bisexualism, who says that it is a new phenomena among American teenagers? An American geneticist. There are indications of bisexualism in the history from the Ancient Greek and beyond. Maybe bisexual individuals have a higher fitness? Men/women are attracted to individuals who show an interest to their own sex and these individuals get to reproduce. In that case bisexual life-style would likely remain in the population.

Answer (score 1):

First, your question makes a few assumptions. We can totally run with those assumptions, but I thought two needed to be noted:

1. There is a genetic predisposition to bisexuality.
2. This genetic predisposition does not already dominate the population. (Perhaps suppressed by social pressure)

A genetic predisposition in a small minority, in order to infiltrate and achieve dominance, would need to either:

- Directly possess advantages over the absence of said predisposition
- Be "luckily" carried by hosts which maintain some other advantage in order to infiltrate the population.

Off the top of my head, some direct advantages of bisexuality could be:

- Arousal of opposite gender with homo/bisexual acts or displays
- Maintenance of psychological and physical fitness during short term gender imbalance
- Self advancement socially regardless of audience's gender
- Frequent physical activity (exercise) in a sedentary culture.

I'm sure the list could go on. Specifically with this sample of potential advantages, a cultural stigma would likely both :

- Suppress the fulfillment of this predisposition, thus leaving it unhindered in their offspring
- Produce reproductive hostility toward those who exhibit signs of this predisposition

Lifting such stigma, and assuming the advantages somehow outweighed the innumerable disadvantages, I would conclude "yes", it is possible for a society to be birthed where sexual exclusion by gender was not even considered.  That is, there would be no such thing as "sexual orientation" in the populace's mind share.

Answer (score 0):

"one American geneticist"?  You realize that that's how you would describe a crackpot, right?  It's not clear to me at all the American youth are "functionally" bisexual.  For one thing, I don't think American high school culture is all that encouraging of boys experimenting with each other, though I can easily imagine straight girls being under pressure to titillate the boys in their group with lesbian displays.